# ajax does not work with opera

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, opera

My ajax code won't work in opera, however, it works with all other major browsers:

```
$(function() {  
$("a").on('click', function(e) {
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    $.ajaxSetup({
        beforeSend:function(xhr) { $('div.imagePlace').animate({height:      '10px'}); },
    });
    $.ajax();
    e.preventDefault();

    setTimeout(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: href,
        dataType: "html",
        success:function(result) {
            $('.imagePlace').html(result)
            $('.imagePlace').animate({height: '500px'})
        }
    });
        }, 400);
});


    });
```

Could anyone see what the problem is in opera ? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the lone `$.ajax();` supposed to do and what **exactly** "does not work"? Is the request not sent? Is the callback not executed? You have to give us more than just "it does not work".

Comment: There is a sliding panel. When click a button ajax request send and the sliding panel goes down. Class of this sliding panel is imagePlace. But this sliding panel does not work so I think request is not sent!

Answer (score 0):

Opera has a debugging tool built in called Dragonfly. Go to the Tools menu -> Advanced ->Opera Dragonfly
If you don't have the File menu bar, click Menu -> Page -> Developer Tools -> Open Opera Dragonfly

Once you have it open (open it on the page that you're working on), click the Scripts tab (it'll probably ask you to refresh the page, do that) and drop down to your external js file. Once you've found your code, you can set a breakpoint on the `$.ajax()` line by clicking on the line number on the left side. Now, trigger your code and you'll see that it will break on that JavaScript line. You can then use the inspection tab (bottom, middle) to ensure that all of your variables are set correctly. You can also step through and debug the JavaScript.

The other thing you'll want to do is add an error function like so:

```
$(function() {  
$("a").on('click', function(e) {
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    $.ajaxSetup({
        beforeSend:function(xhr) { $('div.imagePlace').animate({height:      '10px'}); },
    });
    e.preventDefault();
    setTimeout(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: href,
        dataType: "html",
        success:function(result) {
            $('.imagePlace').html(result)
            $('.imagePlace').animate({height: '500px'})
        }
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(errorThrown);
        }
    });
        }, 400);
});

});
```

See if that gives you any more information.